# Questions about a shuffle function

Tags: javascript

I know there are definitely better ways to shuffle and for that matter worse ways to shuffle but I'm trying to figure out exactly how this function works. As cliche as it is "If you can't explain it to a three year old, you don't understand it". This function would be very hard for me to explain to a three year old. I wrote some comments as to what I think the function does but can someone please describe in detail how every step of this function works most importantly after arr[i]'s value is set to temp.

```
var shuffle = function(array) {
    //creates a copy of the array
    array = array.slice()
    //iterates through the array
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      //generates a random index no longer than the length of the array
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
      //stores the iterated values of array[i]
      var temp = array[i];
      //confusing part!
      array[i] = array[j];
      //confusing part!
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    //returns the newly modified copy of the original array
    return array;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Those three lines are there to swap the values between `array[i]` and `array[j]`.

1. Store value of `array[i]` at `temp`.
2. Store value of `array[j]` at `array[i]`. Now, `array[i]` has the value of `array[j]`.
3. Restore the value from `temp` to `array[j]`. Now, `array[j]` has the actual value of `array[i]`.

After this step, value at `array[i]` will be in `array[j]` and the value of `array[j]` will be in `array[i]`.

And the Algorithm you have implemented is a slightly different version of [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Basically, on every iteration, a random number will be selected (which is strictly lesser than the length of the size of the array). Then, element at the current index (`array[i]`) and the element corresponding to the randomly picked index (`array[j]`) will be swapped.

Comment: So is array[i] = array[j] setting the indexs of array[i] to random indexs? for instance array[i] is 0 and is now a randomly generated index?

Comment: @jharclerode On every iteration, a random number will be selected (which is strictly lesser than the length of the size of the array). Then, element at the current index (`array[i]`) and the element corresponding to the randomly picked index (`array[j]`) will be swapped.

Comment: How does setting array[j] to temp(array[i]) prevent duplicate items? Without it the mutated array would contain duplicates? What does it mean that array[j] has the actual value of array[i] now? Sorry for all of the questions just really want to pick this function apart. @thefourtheye

Comment: @jharclerode Just think that you have two papers in your hands. Now you want to switch the paper in the right hand, with the one in the left hand. How would you do that? Please explain the steps here and I think that would make it easy for me to explain the data swapping :)

Answer (score 0):

The parts you labeled as "confusing" are just swapping the values of the current array element with the randomly selected element. It puts the current value in a temporary variable, replaces the current element with the random element, and then replaces the random element with the temporary.